# Simplify the summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-2}}{(2k-1)^{2m}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-1}}{(2k)^{2m}}$$

can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k)^{-2m}-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2k)^{-2m}$$
???

I was able to do only the first line:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-2}}{(2k-1)^{2m}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2k-1}}{(2k)^{2m}}$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2k-1)^{-2m}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2k)^{-2m}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two sums is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2m}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k)^{-2m}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)^{-2m}.$$

This is zero, since $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k)^{-2m}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)^{-2m}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2m}.$$  It's the "even terms" and "odd terms" trick, going in the other direction.

Comment: is this $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-2m}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k)^{-2m}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)^{-2m}.$$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.